# Site changes behavior when chrome developer tools are open

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So, I very frequently have Chrome developer tools open when I look at sites just to get a sense of how they're put together, what "real" HTML and CSS looks like.

I've started to realize that some sites will actually behave differently when the developer tools are open. The easiest example I can find is [twitter](http://twitter.com). Basically, if you try to trigger infinite scroll when developer tools are open it simply won't work (pic below).

[image: Twitter infinite scroll breaking]

So I have two questions:

1. How can I do this intentionally if I want to?
2. Is there a reason for this behavior and if not, is there a way around it?

Comment: Twitter's infinite scroll works for me with Dev Tools open.

Comment: @Polarize fascinating, what version of Chrome are you using? I'm on 49.0.2623.87

Comment: Currently using 51.0.2692.0 (Canary) but I have tested it on 49.0.2623.110 and it produces the same behaviour.

Comment: @Polarize Operating system? I've had very consistent and repeatable behavior like this across a number of sites

Comment: Windows 10 (64-bit). Tested on Firefox (45.0.1) also and infinite scroll works as expected.

Comment: @Polarize Hmm, I'm on Yosemite. When I reload the page with developer tools up the page actually automatically loads the mobile site instead. This is despite the fact that developer tools are open in a different window.

Comment: That's because you have the mobile emulation enabled. That's the second from the right icon on the top left of the dev tools.

Comment: @user2867288 I do not have mobile emulation enabled. If I did it would be super sensible, but turning it on just breaks the page. Enabling mobile reloads a totally reasonable mobile view.

Comment: What extensions have you installed? Have you been messing with your user agent string?

Comment: Also what's the exclamation point on your "sources" tab telling you?

Comment: Im facing a similar issue, with developer tools enabled some script tags with src attribute aren't executed (most of them are ads or tracking tools). I have tested with firefox and chrome, and both have the same behavior in private/incognito mode.